# como poner un borde a un iframe en wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

ayuda!!

Necesito agregar un border a un iframe dentro de las entradas de blog en wordpress e identificado varias clases y estilos y les agrego el border en el css y los remplazo pero no veo reflejado el resultado en el sitio, ¿Qué puede ser?

```
<iframe src="http://" class="purina-iframe" style="width: 641px; min-width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow-x: hidden;" frameborder="0" width="641px"></iframe>
```

Saludos!

Comment: Que css has intentado aplicar ?

Answer (score 0):

El atributo **frameborder** de la etiqueta **iframe** ya no se admite en HTML5. Se hace desde el CSS. Espero haberte ayudado :)

```html
<iframe src="http://www.peru.gob.pe" class="purina-iframe" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; overflow-x: hiden; border:5px solid peru;"></iframe>
```